# How to prove the sufficient condition for a PDE has positive eigenvalues

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Strauss' textbook says it is $\left[f(x)f'(x)\vphantom{\dfrac11}\right]_{x=a} ^{x=b}<0$, or $=0$.

the assumption is $f''(x)=-\lambda f(x)$ for real $\lambda$. they told me to use Green's first identity and substitute $f=g=X$. So I got : $\int_a^b -\lambda f^2 +(f')^2 \, dx= \left.ff'\vphantom{\dfrac11}\right]_a ^b$. Here I can't proceed. Please help.

Comment: Try to solve for $\lambda$ in the equation you have found. What terms are positive and what terms can have both signs. Try to derive a sufficient condition from this.